# Cannot install from local repo - Redhat 8

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I am working with an offline system and trying to set up a local repo to install packages.  I have my rpms located in /home/user/rpm, and have generated my repodata, which resides in /home/user/rpm/repodata.

I have created test.repo inside /etc/yum/repos.d and have the following configuration.

```
[test]
name=test
baseurl=file:///home/user/rpm
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

However, when trying to do a yum repolist, I am getting

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management.  You can use subscription-manager to register
test                                          0.0 B/s | 0 B    00:00
Failed to download metadata for repo 'test'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'test'
```

I have had no issues in the past with redhat 7, but has something chnaged with redhat 8?

Comment: You did create the repo using `createrepo`?  To install, `yum -y install createrepo_c`

Comment: I ran the createrepo on a separate system which is connected to a network, and then transfered the RPMs and repodata over to the isolated system.